# How to fix "isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types" error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, djongo

I created a Django  (v. 2.1.5) model called Metric that has itself as an embed model, as you can see below:

```py
from djongo import models

class Metric(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
   ...
    dependencies = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container='Metric',
        blank=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'metric'
```

But, when I try to execute the code:

```py
for metric in Metric.objects.all():
```

I get the following error:

```py
  File "/.../python3.6/site-packages/djongo/models/fields.py", line 235, in to_python
    if isinstance(mdl_dict, self.model_container):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

I imagine that this error was caused by the use of single quotation marks on model_container assignment, but I can't remove it, since the model_container is the class itself. Also, I'm not sure if that is the reason.

In any case, what I can do to fix this error?

Comment: Please show the entire `models.py`

Comment: where does `ArrayModelField` come from? what is it?

Comment: @dirkgroten, probably this: https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/array-model-field/

Comment: I can't see any reference to Djongo allowing you to use strings for the model_container parameter. Normally in standard Django you can use the string name or 'self' for things like ForeignKey, but Djongo appears to require the actual type here - which of course is not defined yet in the case of self-referential fields. So, this may not be possible.

Comment: I think it is not possible to have the model embedded inside itself.

Comment: In fact there's an open issue on this: https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/245, although it does not seem to have received any attention.

Comment: Yeah, the problem really seems to be that this can not be done. Now I have to figure out a way to do a similar implementation :(
Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Quoting the API documentation:

> The model of the container must be declared as abstract, thus should not be treated as a collection of its own.

You can only use abstract models as containers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, if the referenced Model is not in the same app, you should use this format

```
    dependencies = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container='app_name.Metric',
        blank=True,
    )
```

instead of just

```
    dependencies = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container='Metric',
        blank=True,
    )
```